# Django select_related and field lookup

Tags: django, django-models, django-select-related

===**Models**===

```
class A(models.Model):
     name= models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)

Class B(models.Model):
     university = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False)
     location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
     b_fk= models.ForeignKey(A)

Class C(models.Model):
     studentclass = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False)
     section = models.CharField(max_length= 10)
     c_fk = models.ForeignKey(B)

class Cfurther(models.Model):
     branch= Models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=Flase)
     number = models.IntegerField()
     cfur_fk = models.ForeignKey(C)

class Info(models.Model):
     info_number = models.IntegerField()
     info = models.CharField(max_length= 12, blank=Flase)
     info_fk = models.ForeignKey(B, related_name= "info_set")

class Infocategory(models.Model):
     find = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=False)
     cat_fk = models.ForeignKey(Info)

class Extra(models.Model):
     extrainfo = models.CharField(max_length=30)
     extra_fk = models.ForeignKey(Infocategory)
```

===**View**===

***Django documentation***

> Returns a QuerySet that will automatically "follow" foreign-key
>   relationships, selecting that additional related-object data when it
>   executes its query.
>
> select_related is limited to single-valued relationships - foreign key
>   and one-to-one.
>
> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

I have written Following Queryset to fetch model fields (all the relationships are one-to-many)

```
myquery = Info.objects.select_related().filter(info_number__iexact = 123)
```

- I want to traverse from **Info Model** toward Upper and lower models
- I don't have problem in getting **Class A** records with select_related() in the template, but is it possible to **get all the model fields with select_related in my case (Class B, C, Cfurther, Infocategory, Extra)?**
- If not do I have to create new queryset? or what select_related() will work?

I am little bit confused regarding **select_related** field lookup

Answer (score 4):

You can traverse through all the relationships as deep as you want just through the standard Django API. `select_related` doesn't do anything special in setting up the relationships; it merely allows you to reduce the number of DB queries by performing joins in advance (instead of looking up each foreign key as it's accessed).

However, as the docs state, `select_related` only works with Foreign Keys and OneToOneFields. It doesn't work with ManyToManyFields at all. Additionally, you can only follow reverse relationship with `select_related` if it's a OneToOneField. Reverse ForeignKeys are not supported. Finally, by default `select_related` only follows fields that have `null=False`. If it's a NULL-able field, you must explicitly tell `select_related` to follow it:

```
SomeModel.objects.select_related('some_nullable_field')
```

Once Django 1.4 hits, you'll have access to a new method called `prefetch_related` which works like `select_related` but supports ManyToManyFields and reverse ForeignKey relationships.

Comment: You just repeated what I have already mentioned. I am looking for solution rather then documentation!

Comment: The solution is the documentation. As long as you're not following a reverse foreign key or a many-to-many, you can `select_related` whatever you want. What's the problem?